# Unable to find the log file of WebJob in Azure

Tags: c#, nlog, azure-webjobs

I have created a WebJob in Azure. I have used Nlog and point the log file to the "base directory" of the WebJob's exe file. Web job is created and it is running successfully without any errors. Also, Nlog is creating the log file in my local system. But in azure, I am not able to find the log file. I went into the "app_data\jobs\triggered" folder and found the job which I have created. But the log file is not getting created. I am able to write and see the console log in azure.

**EDIT**

Program.cs

```
using NLog; 
using System;

namespace FacilitationPortal.WebJob {
    class Program
    {
        static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string nlogServicePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "NLog-WebSchedulerService.config";

        NLog.LogManager.Configuration = new NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration(nlogServicePath, true);
        logger.Debug("Initializing the Web Scheduler Service");
        Console.WriteLine("Initializing the Web Scheduler Service");
        StartServices();
    }

    private static void StartServices()
    {
        logger.Debug("INSIDE - START SERVICES");
    }
    } 
}
```

NLog-WebSchedulerService.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">
  <targets >
    <target xsi:type="File" name="logfile"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/WebScheduler.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true:padding=5} ${gdc:item=hostname} ${gdc:item=useremail} (${logger} - ${mdc:item=actionname})  ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            archiveFileName ="${basedir}/logs/WebScheduler.${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm}.{#}.zip"
            archiveNumbering ="Sequence"
            maxArchiveFiles="30"
            fileAttributes="Compressed"
            enableArchiveFileCompression = "true">
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile">
    </logger>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Console.WriteLine() is printing the log in azure console. But logger.Debug() is not creating log file in the place where the exe is present. If I run the same application in my local system, log file is creating.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post related code please ?

Comment: I replace ``${basedir}`` with an existing physical directory, such as ``fileName="D:\home\data\logs\WebScheduler.log"``, and I find the logs is created in Azure, you can try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, using your `NLog-WebSchedulerService.config` and deploying a continuously running WebJob to Azure, I can find the logs under `D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\WebJob1\1hxylleo.lzh\logs` folder, you can check if your logs file under `D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered` folder.

[image]

Besides, as I mentioned in my early comment, you can specify an existing physical directory on Azure to store the logs, such as `fileName="D:\home\data\logs\WebScheduler.log"`, instead of storing the logs under `D:\local\Temp` folder.